# Dangers in using parallel or series resistors for buck feedback divider

Tags: resistors, integrated-circuit, buck

I have multiple adjustable DC/DC buck converters in a design and I'm looking to save lines in the BOM for assembly. Is there any significant drawback to using more than two resistors in a feedback network?

For example, if I need R1 to be 300k and R2 to be 150k can I replace a single 300k R1 resistor with 2 150k's in series? Assuming I use high precision resistors and can tolerate an increased ±% output tolerance what other negatives might I encounter?

Same question applies for resistors in parallel.

[image: DC/DC Converter]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using multiple standard value resistors in the way you suggest (to stay away from hard to find parts or for BoM proliferation reduction) is a very common practice.

Unless you are trying to get the best possible predicted reliability (as found in [MIL-HDBK-217](http://www.t-cubed.com/faq_217.htm)) there really is no practical downside providing you have space on the PCB (although if you cannot fit a couple of extra 0402 parts, things must be *really* tight).

Note that MIL-HDBK-217 reliability predictions are really a numbers game, so minimising components maximises reliability, all other things being equal.

Note that if you replace a 300k, 1% part with two 150k, 1% parts, you still yield 300k, 1%

Comment: In reality, slightly increasing the number of unstressed components has very little effect on reliability, of course. Worst-case tolerance is no worse, and typical might be a bit better (or not).

Comment: Of course, Spehro; I was looking at the extreme case only for reliability and tolerances are generally never worse in a measurable way.